# Product of 3 Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is this identity true for all possible values of $A,B$ and $C$?
$$A^TBC = C^TBA$$
where either

1. $A,B,C$ are square matrices of same size
2. $A$ and $C$ are vectors of size $n$ and $B$ is square matrix of size $n\times n$

Comment: Yes I guess. Can we use that for above proof?

Comment: Have you tried any examples?

Comment: The identity would imply that a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix commutes with every $n\times n$ matrix (take $C$ the identity and $A$ symmetric). Any chance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall, to prove that a statement is not an identity (an equality that holds for all $A, B, C$), you need only find one counterexample that satisfies the premise, but fails to satisfy the equality/identity.

---

$(1)$ Does the identity hold for *all* $A, B, C$ where $A, B, C$ are $n\times n$ square matrices for some $n$? For example, consider the following matrices:

Let $$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}\
1 &2\\
1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
,\quad B=
\begin{bmatrix}\
\,\,1 & 1 \\
-1 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix},\quad
C=
\begin{bmatrix}\
2 & -1\\
\,\,0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}.\
$$

- You'll first need to find $A^T$ and $C^T$.
- Then compute $A^TBC$ and $C^TBA$.
- Does $A^TBC = C^TBA$?

---

$(2)$ Does the identity hold for all $A, B, C$ when $A$ and $C$ are each an $n\times 1$ column vector and $B$ is an $n\times n$ square matrix? ($A$ and $C$ must be $n\times 1$ column vectors if $A^TBC$ and $C^TBA$ are to be defined.)

- Note that $A^TBC$ and $C^TBA$ each evaluate to a scalar.
- Try experimenting with different possibilities for $A, B, C$. Start simple; for example, try working with $n = 2$.
- Again, if you can find $A, B, C$ such that $A^TBC \neq C^TBA$, then $(2)$ cannot hold for *all* such $A, B, C$.

---